# Pip list versus conda list show different package versions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, anaconda, conda

**Summary**
Conda list pillow and pip list show different versions of pillow. What version is python attempting to import?

-Edit- I can import PIL from python, which is not seen by conda list nor pip list

**Executed code**
When I run this from anaconda prompt in my_envrionment (DL_Menarini):

```
(at prompt (DL_Menarini) C:\Users\ZeuneLL>)
>conda list pillow
# packages in environment at C:\Users\ZeuneLL\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\DL_Menarini:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
pillow                    6.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi

>pip list
Package                       Version
----------------------------- ---------
...
Pillow                        6.2.1
... (other packages not shown in post for brevity)
```

I don't understand why they show different versions. Running both

```
>pip uninstall pillow
>conda remove pillow
```

Removes pillow (pip list/conda list show no version of pillow). After

```
>conda install Pillow=6.2.1=py36hdc69c19_0
```

Conda list pillow and pip list pillow both show version 6.2.1. What is different?

```
> python
>>> import pil
>>> import Pillow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Pillow'
>>> import sys
>>> sys.prefix
'C:\\Users\\ZeuneLL\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\envs\\DL_Menarini'
>>> exit()
```

So I can import pil in python, but pil is not seen by conda list nor pip list. So I guess there is a path problem.

**System background**
Windows 10-64 bit. Conda list python shows version 3.6.8 (but 3.6.5 in conda info).

```
> python
>>> for path in sys.path: print(path)
...

C:\Users\ZeuneLL\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\DL_Menarini\python36.zip
C:\Users\ZeuneLL\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\DL_Menarini\DLLs
C:\Users\ZeuneLL\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\DL_Menarini\lib
C:\Users\ZeuneLL\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\DL_Menarini
C:\Users\ZeuneLL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages
C:\Users\ZeuneLL\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\DL_Menarini\lib\site-packages
C:\Users\ZeuneLL\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\DL_Menarini\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\Users\ZeuneLL\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\DL_Menarini\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\Users\ZeuneLL\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\DL_Menarini\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
>>> exit()


>Conda info

     active environment : DL_Menarini
    active env location : C:\Users\ZeuneLL\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\DL_Menarini
            shell level : 2
       user config file : C:\Users\ZeuneLL\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\ZeuneLL\.condarc
          conda version : 4.6.14
    conda-build version : 3.10.5
         python version : 3.6.5.final.0
       base environment : C:\Users\ZeuneLL\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\ZeuneLL\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\ZeuneLL\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\ZeuneLL\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\ZeuneLL\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\ZeuneLL\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\ZeuneLL\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.6.14 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.6.5 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.16299
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Comment: I was previously installing all needed packages I could find from conda, and then installing the rest through pip. This is bad practice as it can cause weird things like the situation above. One way to find more packages is to add the conda-forge 'conda config --add channels conda-forge`.

Answer (score 2):

You've probably solved this a long time ago already, but because I don't have enough reputation to comment on your question and ask for a follow up, I will have to do it here. Just in case you still haven't figured it out, or you're someone else in a similar situation, it all depends on your current setup. Generally, if you install a package with one of them (i.e. either pip or conda), stick to it.

I know it's hard to remember which one you used, but nowadays I always look at my conda list to see if the package is under pypi, BEFORE I update it, to ensure I use the correct package manager. It's a pain, but it can help save you a lot of headaches later. In general, while I love how much faster pip is, it is more prone to breaking your environment than conda. Conda-Forge is usually just as updated as PyPi, so if I were you, I'd avoid using pip and just stick to conda/conda-forge.

Comment: I use conda if I can, pip if I must (for latest tensorflow release). Even using conda I have to specify versions for some packages to get a working environment.  And my main issue is resolved, even though I still don't understand why pip list and conda list give me something different.

Comment: Yup! Same here! If I had to take a wild guess, it probably has something to do with the original installation, and setup of the PATH, and all that. I know in the beginning when I installed with pip, it wouldn't even show up in my conda list, so it was definitely installing somewhere else. I thought I fixed it, but I still get the same issue as you from time to time. 

Oh, and one trick I learned recently: if you're looking for a specific package, you don't have to list your entire environment. For your pillow example above: pip list | grep pillow will return just pillow. Same for conda list!

Comment: I also moved from Anaconda to Miniconda. It takes more space when you have a lot of environments, but so far I'm not in environment dysfunction hell anymore. Thanks for the tips.